# htaccess file doesn't work in subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp

Before I changed anything on my server, when I access `example.com/dev`, it goes to `example.com/godigitell_new/dev`.

I have a cake php project in the subdirectory `example.com/godigitell_new/dev/taskmanagercake/` and I am trying to redirect `example.com/dev/taskmanagercake/` to that URL.

In the `taskmangercake` folder I have written an `.htacess` file like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But when I try to access `example.com/dev/taskmanagercake/`, it results in the following error:

> The requested URL /godigitell_new/godigitell_new/dev/taskmanagercake/app/webroot/index.php was not found.

Please notice that it contains `/godigitell_new/godigitell_new/` (twice).

Can someone please help me to sort out this issue?

I have attached the screenshot of the error:

[image: error screen]

Comment: Do  you have this `godigitell_new` as part of your document root?

Comment: @panamaJack : yeah my document root have godigitell_new...       my root looks like ths /godigitell_new/dev/

Comment: You are probably redirecting twice (once in `/dev`, once again in `taskmanagercake/`. Check if you have a redirection there too. You probably don't even have to add your new `.htaccess` at all, did you try that first?